# How to stop a service before scheduled shutdown reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I want to plan a shutdown of a `ubuntu` server as follows:

`shutdown -r 12:30`

Problem: first I want to make sure that my webserver is shut down (eg to clear up some resources gracefully). Normally I'd be executing `systemctl tomcat stop`, but how can I plan that right before the shutdown?

Or will the shutdown command automatically trigger a `stop` command on any running services, so I won't have to care about it?

Comment: This is normally handled by the service manager during shutdown.

Comment: _Or will the shutdown command automatically trigger a stop command on any running services, so I won't have to care about it?_ <- correct (usually)

Comment: should be automatic. it depends on the systemd unit content. please post it.

Comment: What systemd unit content do you mean? could you give a command?